# Вызов кода при повторном запуске программы

Tags: c#

Привет ХэшКод, скажите вот я хочу сделать так: если программа первый раз запущена, то она открывается нормально, а если 2-й, 3-й и т.д., то срабатывал бы код

```
this.Hide();
```

**UPDATE**

Я сделал такой код

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var mutex = new Mutex(false, id))
            {
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), false))
                        {
                            this.Hide();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (AbandonedMutexException)
                    {
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Проверка повторного вхождения хорошо делается на мьютексах:

```
const string id = "..."; // GUID

static void Main(string[] args) {
    using (var mutex = new Mutex(false, id)) {
        try {
            try {
                if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), false)) {
                    // TODO: Вызвать this.Hide, а еще лучше просто выйти
                }
            }
            catch (AbandonedMutexException) {
            }
        }
        finally {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Обновил первый пост, код почему-то не работает(

Answer (score 0):

Зачем?

1. Если очень хочется и ты имеешь ввиду закрытие программы ПОЛНОЕ, т.е. она не будет висеть в трее или в фоне, тогда надо сделать какой нибудь проперти файл и в нем хранить флаг - кол-во запусков программы, а при запуске его проверять и обрабатывать.
2. Если в фоне, можно хранить в флаг в переменной.

Comment: Да но как сделать,я  при помощи переменной уже пытался делать, не получилось http://hashcode.ru/questions/93588/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно освобождать мьютекс не сразу, а при закрытии программы.

Ещё могу порекомендовать использовать класс `System.Diagnostics.Process` для получения предыдущей копии процесса.

Примерно так:

```
var current_proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var same_procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(current_proc.ProcessName).Where(p =>
  p.Id != current_proc.Id && p.MainModlue.FileName 
  == current_proc.MainModlue.FileName).ToList();

if (same_procs.Count > 0)
  this.Hide();
```